# How to fix module fuse not found error?

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, fuse, modprobe

I used to be able to mount a NTFS formatted drive (read only) on my Ubuntu Linux (9.04) Sheevaplug. I was chasing the impossible dream of being able to mount it for both read and write and somehow messed up my computer system. Now I can't even get it mounted read only:

```
root@debian:~# modprobe fuse
FATAL: Module fuse not found.
root@debian:~# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/drobo/
FATAL: Module fuse not found.
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

How can I get it working again? I'm new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

FUSE is required by the ntfs-3g driver, and should be in the repositories.

To revert to the kernel ntfs driver, use `mount -t ntfs` or remove the ntfs-3g package entirely.

Comment: That doesn't work, because the kernel ntfs driver is not working. Doing that gets the same error message as above.